# sliding the icon on the button

Tags: java, android, button, android-button, material-components-android

I want to move the icon on the button a little bit to the right.

**Button code**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:width="55sp"
    android:height="40sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content". 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/share"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `paddingStart` to shift entire content to the `Button` to right, but if you want `text` to stay at centre, add a negative value padding for `drawablePadding` as in

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:width="55sp"
    android:height="40sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content". 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:drawablePadding="-10dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/share"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `MaterialButton` and use the **`iconGravity`** attribute to `textStart` or `start`.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="BUTTON"
    app:iconGravity="textStart"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_24px" />
```

You can also add the `app:iconPadding="xxdp"` attribute.

[image]